# Socket IO | How to get the client transport type on the serverside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

**I need to know what transport method a client is using for some conditional statements on the nodeJS serverside.**

Does anyone know how I can get that information? Is it held within the client object?

Comment: There is no easy way to get this information. The source does not make it easily accessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In socket.io 0.7.6

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
    console.log(io.transports[client.id].name);
});
```

Answer (score 25):

As of Socket.IO 1.0:

**Client**:

```
socket.on('connect', function() {
    console.log(socket.io.engine.transport.name);
}
```

**Server**:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log(socket.conn.transport.name);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

April 2012, this works:  socket.transport

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you can find it if you dig in the internals of a client object, although without knowing why you need this I have to recommend against this kind of check for 2 reasons:

Firstly, since it isn't in the API the developers have absolutely no responsibility to keep things backward compatible, so any given version might implement/store that information differently, which will only ripple into your own development and cause problems.

Secondly, and more importantly, I suggest you rethink your design, the communication with the server thru socket.io is built to be *transparent* to the method being used. There should be no difference on either side. That's the purpose of the library, designing an app that behaves otherwise is totally orthogonal to that idea.

Comment: This problem is the reason I want the know the transport type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6280569/socket-io-xhr-polling-delay-on-disconnection

Comment: @davin After digging through the internals its not actually possible.

Comment: @Raynos, I thought I remembered seeing a `url` property somewhere once in the client object (or a sub-object), couldn't you regex it out of there using the same conventions the library itself uses?

Comment: Maybe, I have feeling yes, but I don't know where that `url` lives or what its standard format is. And it's a **HACK** as mentioned.

Comment: @Raynos, yes, I already mentioned it was dangerous relying on non-public things like that; no need to shout :)

Comment: @davin not at you. Just wanted to re-enforce the idea that this is a bad idea :)

Answer (score 2):

for reference's sake and google stumbles:-
in case anyone is still using v0.9 (or possibly earlier)
you can access this info from client side like this:

```
var socket = io.connect();
console.log(socket.socket.transport.name); //log the name of the transport being used.
```

answer found on google groups https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/socket_io/yx_9wJiiAg0

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will solve your problem. My trick here is to save the transport type on the HTTP Request object once the client connects. You can then pick it up in your callback later. First we tweak the Listener class:

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
io.Listener.prototype._onConnectionOld = io.Listener.prototype._onConnection;
io.Listener.prototype._onConnection = function(transport, req, res, up, head){
  req.socketIOTransport = transport;  // Take note of the transport type
  this._onConnectionOld.call(this, transport, req, res, up, head);
};
```

And then below in the body of your app:

```
var socket = io.listen(app),
socket.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log(client.request.socketIOTransport);  // Lets check that transport
    // ...
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
io.connect.managers['connect url/port'].engine.transport
```