# Transmitting data continuously from Chrome for Android to Node.js server using Socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, delay, throttling

I need to **transmit the touch position** in *Chrome for Android* **continuously** to a `Node.js` server using `Socket.io`. However, I guess, the transmission is too fast. The first few values receive the server (For the first touch about six values, later only two or three values), then there seems to be a traffic jam. For many seconds the server receives nothing. Then, suddenly all missed values suddenly arrive at the server. But not continuously...

I think I must **reduce the traffic from client to server** by letting the client only emit in an **interval** of 500ms.
**[This video](https://youtu.be/U3ZBG6k9Pkc)** demonstrates the last of the following options.

What I've tried so far (without success):

- Wrapping a setInterval function around the emit function in the client code:

  ```
  setInterval( function(){ 
      Socket.emit( 'position', posX )
  }, 500);
  ```
- Regulating the emission with `Date.now()` in the client code:

  ```
  var timestamp = 0;

  // ...

  if (Date.now() - timestamp >= 500) {
      Socket.emit( 'position', posX );
      timestamp = Date.now();
  }
  ```
- Throttling the `touchmove` event in the client code using the `underscore` library

  ```
  $('#canvas').on("touchmove", _.throttle(function (ev) {
      var e = ev.originalEvent;
      var posX = logCounter + " : " + e.targetTouches[0].pageX;
      $('#div').text(posX);
      socket.emit('position', posX);
      logCounter++;
      return false;
  }, 500));
  ```

  Let me mention that this snippet logs `posX` both on a HTML `div` in the web page *AND* in the console of the server. The browser logs every 500ms as expected, but the server (through `Socket.io`) logs only in the beginning as expected, then break, then all missing values at once.

The project is on **[Github](https://github.com/fabifiess/syncPos)**.

Any ideas how to realize a smooth (continuous) transmission?

**Edit:**

I figured out that this problem only exists with the Chrome browser on my Android phone and on my Android tablet.
This application works fine for Firefox for Android, Opera for Android and Safari for iOs.

How can I outsmart Chrome?

Comment: Do you think that doing buffering in the destination and then replay the events in order could be a workaround?

Comment: you can create a vector from touch positions, calculate a line equation and just send the equation parameters to the server. It is not that accurate but it saves a lot of traffic.

Comment: @rodrigoap: Wouldn´t it be better to buffer data already on client side before being transmitted to server?

Comment: @ Amir: Great idea. How would you do this?

Comment: The most important question is - what are you doing with the data? If it's just storing it - there are a lot of options. If you need to show it to others - there's a lot of problems :)

Comment: If you buffer data on client side and then transmit it you are in the same place. Take for example video buffering, you see it as a continuum while in reality is not.

Comment: @ Andrey Popov: This is a quite simple smart home application: you see a color wheel in a browser. An LED changes its color to the color of the color wheel at the touch position. I just simplified the code for pointing out the problem.

Comment: Mind the Edit: This problem only exists with Chrome for Android! But why that??

Comment: @wurstbrotrest There appear to be issues with how Chrome handles touchmove.   Have you tried ev.preventDefault() in your handler?

Comment: Yes, I have tried this earlier, but `ev.preventDefault()` is not compatible with the `throttle`function, that´s why I´m using `return false`instead.